# Remove # from URL in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I am redirecting from an old sites URLs. One set of links in particular was used for start and stop times for a video player.

```
http://foo.com/index.php?option=com_tvwplayer&eventID=2015020086#start=3263&stop=5621
```

I was able to redirect the base fine by using this:

```
if ($option ~ com_tvwplayer){
   set $eventID $arg_eventID;
   set $args '';
   set $nArg '?customID=';
   rewrite ^.*$ $uri/watch/$nArg$eventID  permanent;
}
```

This works great for:

```
http://foo.com/index.php?option=com_tvwplayer&eventID=2015020086
```

changing it to:

```
http://foo.com/watch/?customID=2015020086
```

But that # in the URL for time indicators needs to be removed or replaced with a & in order for it to look like this:

```
http://foo.com/watch/?customID=2015020086&start=3263&stop=5621
```

Any thoughts or fancy RegEx to get this to work?

Comment: You cannot do this because browsers do not send `#...` part of URL to server.

Comment: Are you trying to do this on the front-end in javascript? Can you give a little more context?

Answer (score -1):

You could try `sed`:

```
URL="http://foo.com/index.php?option=com_tvwplayer&eventID=2015020086#start=3263&stop=5621"
NEW_URL=`echo $URL | sed 's/#/&/g'`
echo $NEW_URL
```

This code pipes your `URL` containing the offending #'s into a `sed` which finds and replaces all #'s with &'s and saves it to a new variable called `NEW_URL`.